# Ruby: Can I convert a number input to a fixed sized byte array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, byte

I am pretty new in ruby word, I did java a lot in my previous company.
The condition is I want to create a fixed sized file. And my idea is to create a byte array and filled with input number of elements. For example, if I want to create a 2GB file, it will fill 2M items into the Byte array(array has 4M size).
I can implement it by using a long value as input, and do >> or << to help me fill the byte array and use the elements to validate the created file.

```
key[0] = (byte) 1;
key[1] = (byte) (i >> 24 & 0xFF);
key[2] = (byte) (i >> 16 & 0xFF);
key[3] = (byte) (i >> 8 & 0xFF);
key[4] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);
```

But in ruby since it is dynamic, I am kind of meet a blocker here, I am thinking to use a 24 byte array to mimic long variables, I know this is kindle of complex, but is there any other better option? Would be really appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to really, strictly, **force** an `Array` to be "un-growable" in ruby - like you could in Java. I think you would need to rely on the code being sufficiently well written that it doesn't do anything "naughty" to grow it.

Comment: For example, you could define your own setters for the `Array` to help ensure this. For example, undefine the `Array#<<` method; and undefine/override the `Array#[]=` method to check that the index is in-bounds; and likewise for `Array#insert`; and likewise for `Array#append`; and... anything else I missed?...

Comment: This could be a subclass like `FixedSizeArray` with your custom behaviour to ensure it's ungrowable-after-initialising. But still, it would be **possible** for code to just define its own setter method or whatever, dynamically.

Comment: Well... I guess there is one way you could strictly do this: You can call C methods directly from (MRI) ruby, or [call Java methods directly from JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby). So if you really wanted to enforce this 100% strictly, then you could do it all in Java and call invoke the code from ruby.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I understand. My initiate idea is to create a final block size, and create a block size byte array. But you mentioned the array could be growable which i should care more. It's really many differences in ruby world.

Comment: I see. Will check that then. Appreciate it.

Comment: @TomLord : Wouldn't `Array#pack` be what he's looking for?

Comment: @Fravadona My understanding was that this question has actually got nothing to do with manipulating byes. It's about wanting to have a data set of fixed (limited) size that cannot be "accidentally" grown.

Answer (score 1):

### In-Memory Approaches to Simulated Fixed-Length Arrays

I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but *by design* Ruby doesn't let you set a fixed size for things like Array. The closest you're likely to get is to assign and then truncate to fit.

As a basic example, let's assume I want a circular buffer of 5 elements, and I never want to to "grow" beyond that. I could do:

```rb
CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE = 5

circular_buffer = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
circular_buffer.push 5, 6, 7
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

if circular_buffer.size > CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE
  circular_buffer.shift(
    circular_buffer.size - CIRCULAR_BUFFER_SIZE
  )
end

circular_buffer
#=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Eventually, you could turn this into a custom class or a descendant of Array that implements this behavior automatically when calling #push, #append, #<<, #shift, #unshift, or #[]=.

When writing out to disk, you can truncate your Array as above before [packing it](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-pack). Alternatively, if you're writing your file as a LIFO, you could write to a StringIO object first, [truncate it](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-truncate) as if you were calling [File#truncate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/File.html#method-i-truncate), then write it out to disk normally. Either should work if the goal is simply to avoid writing more than *n* bytes to disk.